# Django char field with choices list

Tags: django

So, I want to implement a char field with choices list. The idea is that it looks like a common char field but when you click on it and start typing something in, a dropdown menu pops up and you can choose something (also it sorts choices depending on what user types in). How do we do that?

Comment: What you are describing feels like it has nothing to do with Django (which is a webserver framework) and more of a frontend thing. Can you please show the relevant code you have?

Comment: Uh, honestly i can't because that's the question :). It may be a forms.CharField with some widget or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like [**`django-easy-select2`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-easy-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). You can install this (in your local environment) with:

```
pip3 install django-easy-select2
```

Next you add `'easy_select2'` to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps):

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'easy_select2',
    # …,
]

# …
```

Now you can make use of the `Select2` widget in your `Form` (or `ModelForm`):

```
from easy_select2 import Select2

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'my_field': Select2
        }
```